# C program with AVX and AVX2 instructions exceeding RAM limit of 2GB

Tags: c, performance, memory-leaks, avx, avx2

I am writing a C program to locate quoted text which begins with a "-symbol and ends either with a "-symbol or with a double newline character \n. To make it as fast as possible I am using AVX and AVX2 instructions. The PC I am running it on over SSH kicks any process using more than 2GB of RAM.

I don't understand what part of my code is using all this memory. Could anyone guide me in the right direction or give me some insight?

This is the fuction which gets called. The text file I am using is a 1.2GB txt file.

detect_quotes.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DEFINE_INTERFACE 0
#define bad_call(exec) { print_usage(exec); return 1; }
#define bad_alloc() { fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
#define test_alloc(expr) { if (!(expr)) { bad_alloc(); } }

void
print_usage(const char *exec)
{
    printf("Usage: %s (FILE|-)\n", exec);
    printf("       EXAMPLE: %s text.txt\n", exec);
    printf("       EXAMPLE: gzip -dc text.txt.gz | %s -\n", exec);
    printf("       EXAMPLE: echo \"my interesting \\\"test\\\"\" | %s -\n", exec);
}

// -- Text data structure -----------------------------------------------------

typedef struct {
    /** The text data to analyze. */
    char *characters;

    /** The number of characters in this text. */
    size_t len;

    /** The capacity of the `characters` buffer.*/
    size_t cap;
} Text;

Text
alloc_text()
{
    Text text;
    text.len = 0;
    text.cap = 1024 * 512; // half a megabyte
    text.characters = aligned_alloc(32, sizeof(char) * text.cap);
    test_alloc(text.characters);
    memset(text.characters, 0, text.cap);
    return text;
}

void
require_capacity(Text *text, size_t cap)
{
    // maintain an aditional 64 bytes of zeros after the last character
    if (text->cap > cap + 64)
        return;
    char *new_characters = aligned_alloc(32, sizeof(char) * text->cap * 2);
    test_alloc(new_characters);
    memset(new_characters, 0, text->cap * 2);
    memcpy(new_characters, text->characters, sizeof(char) * text->len);
    free(text->characters);

    text->cap *= 2;
    text->characters = new_characters;
}

void
dealloc_text(Text *text)
{
    text->cap = 0;
    text->len = 0;
    free(text->characters);
    text->characters = NULL;
}

void
load_text(char *file, Text *text)
{
    FILE *fh;
    if (strcmp(file, "-") == 0)
    {
        fh = stdin;
    }
    else
    {
        fh = fopen(file, "r");
    }
    if (fh == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file %s\n", file);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    size_t chars_read = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        require_capacity(text, text->len + 1024);
        char *buf = text->characters + text->len;
        if ((chars_read = fread(buf, sizeof(char), 1024, fh)) == 0)
            break;

        if (ferror(fh))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "error reading file %s\n", file);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        text->len += chars_read;
    }

    if (strcmp(file, "-") != 0)
        fclose(fh);
}

void
print_text(Text *text)
{
    fwrite(text->characters, sizeof(char), text->len, stdout);
}

void
print_text_quote(Text *text, int quote_begin, int quote_end)
{
    if (quote_begin >= quote_end)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid quote begin and end positions: %d and %d\n",
                quote_begin, quote_end);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char *begin = text->characters + quote_begin;
    int len = quote_end - quote_begin + 1;
    printf("<<<");
    fwrite(begin, sizeof(char), len, stdout);
    printf(">>>");
    putchar('\n');
}

// -- Output data structure ---------------------------------------------------

typedef struct {
    size_t begin;
    size_t end;
} OutputPair;

typedef struct {
    OutputPair *pairs;
    size_t len;
    size_t cap;
} Output;

Output
alloc_output()
{
    Output output;
    output.len = 0;
    output.cap = 1024;
    output.pairs = malloc(sizeof(OutputPair) * output.cap);
    test_alloc(output.pairs);

    return output;
}

/** Function to push a quote starting at position `begin` and ending
 * at postion `end` to the output. */
void
push_pair(Output *output, int begin, int end)
{
    if (output->len == output->cap)
    {
        output->cap *= 2;
        output->pairs = realloc(output->pairs, sizeof(Output) * output->cap);
        test_alloc(output->pairs);
    }

    output->pairs[output->len].begin = begin;
    output->pairs[output->len].end = end;
    output->len++;
}

void
dealloc_output(Output *output)
{
    output->len = 0;
    output->cap = 0;
    free(output->pairs);
    output->pairs = NULL;
}


// ---External symbols: DEFINED IN `submission.c` -------------

void
detect_quotes(Text *text, Output *output);

#include "submission.c"

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int
main(int argc, char **args)
{
    if (argc != 2) bad_call(args[0]);

    char *file = args[1];
    Text text = alloc_text();
    Output output = alloc_output();

    load_text(file, &text);
    //print_text(&text);

    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;

    begin = clock();
    detect_quotes(&text, &output);

    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

//     Debug print: print out all the quotes that were found
//    for (size_t i = 0; i < output.len; ++i)
//    {
//        size_t b = output.pairs[i].begin;
//        size_t e = output.pairs[i].end;
//        printf("quote %lu, %lu: ", b, e);
//        print_text_quote(&text, b, e);
//    }

    printf("\n%lu quotes detected in %f seconds", output.len, time_spent);
    printf("\nThat is %.2f MiB/s\n", (text.len / (1024*1024))/time_spent);

    dealloc_output(&output);
    dealloc_text(&text);
}


This is the main function
    
    int main(int argc, char **args){
        if (argc != 2) bad_call(args[0]);
    
        char *file = args[1];
        Text text = alloc_text();
        Output output = alloc_output();
    
        load_text(file, &text);
        //print_text(&text);
    
        clock_t begin, end;
        double time_spent;
    
        begin = clock();
        detect_quotes(&text, &output);
    
        end = clock();
        time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    
    //     Debug print: print out all the quotes that were found
    //    for (size_t i = 0; i < output.len; ++i)
    //    {
    //        size_t b = output.pairs[i].begin;
    //        size_t e = output.pairs[i].end;
    //        printf("quote %lu, %lu: ", b, e);
    //        print_text_quote(&text, b, e);
    //    }
    
        printf("\n%lu quotes detected in %f seconds", output.len, time_spent);
        printf("\nThat is %.2f MiB/s\n", (text.len / (1024*1024))/time_spent);
    
        dealloc_output(&output);
        dealloc_text(&text);
    }
```

And submission.c

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "stdint.h"

#ifndef DEFINE_INTERFACE
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char *characters;
    size_t len;
    size_t cap;
} Text;

typedef struct Output Output;

void
push_pair(Output *output, int begin, int end);

#endif


void __attribute__ ((noinline))
detect_quotes(Text *text, Output *output) {
    __m256i q32 = _mm256_set1_epi8(0x22);
    __m256i nl32 = _mm256_set1_epi8(0x0A);

    int len32 = text->len / 32 * 32;
    len32 = 0;
    int start = 0;
    bool isStartSet = false;
    bool isNlActive = false;
    unsigned int nlPrevLast = 0;
    unsigned int nlThisLast = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for (; i < len32; i += 32) {
        nlCmp = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i *) &text->characters[i]);

        __m256i qCmp = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(nlCmp, q32);
        __m256i nlCmp = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(nlCmp, nl32);

        unsigned int qMask = _mm256_movemask_epi8(qCmp);
        unsigned int nlMask = _mm256_movemask_epi8(nlCmp);

        nlThisLast = (nlMask & 1 << 31) >> 31;
        nlMask = nlMask & ((nlMask >> 1) | nlPrevLast);

        if (qMask != 0 || (isStartSet && nlMask != 0)) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 32; ++j) {
                if (qMask & 1) {
                    if (isStartSet) {
                        push_pair(output, start, i + j);
                        isStartSet = false;
                    } else {
                        start = i + j;
                        isStartSet = true;
                    }
                } else if (nlMask & 1) {
                    if (isStartSet) {
                        push_pair(output, start, i + j);
                        isStartSet = false;
                    }
                }
                qMask >>= 1;
                nlMask >>= 1;
            }
        }
        nlPrevLast = nlThisLast;
    }
    if (nlPrevLast != 0){
        isNlActive = true;
    }
    for ( ; i < text->len; i++) {
        if (text->characters[i] == '"') {
            if (isStartSet) {
                push_pair(output, start, i);
                isStartSet = false;
            } else {
                start = i;
                isStartSet = true;
            }
            isNlActive = false;
        } else if (text->characters[i] == '\n') {
            if (isStartSet) {
                if (isNlActive) {
                    push_pair(output, start, i);
                } else {
                    isNlActive = true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            isNlActive = false;
        }
    }
}
```

They are compiled using this make file

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -mavx -mavx2 -O3

detect_quotes: detect_quotes.c submission.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o detect_quotes detect_quotes.c

detect_quotes_g: detect_quotes.c submission.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -g -o detect_quotes_g detect_quotes.c

detect_quotes_gprof: detect_quotes.c submission.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -g -pg -o detect_quotes_gprof detect_quotes.c
```

And at last an example of the text file can be downloaded [here from my Google Drive this is a 41 MB txt file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XBtFlu8-BcV7aCMW0p1GBWMkMFs0Lno0/view?usp=sharing).

To run the program after compiling use the txt file as first and only argument: detect_quotes.exe gutenbergsmall.txt

Comment: Is your code actually using up the memory? Isn't it failing for some other reason?

Comment: The code runs without issues on my local PC using a smaller text file and it runs on the remote machine with the smaller text file. Only when using the 1.2GB file does my program get kicked.

Comment: But your "smaller" file is large enough that `len32` is non-zero?  Sounds like the problem isn't SIMD, but rather memory management in the caller of this function.  Or the pair_push that this function calls.  Maybe mmap the file instead of reading it into a 1.2GB buffer, or read and process incrementally in small chunks.

Comment: The smaller file is 23MB so `len32` will be more than lage enough. Also tried with 514MB file, no issues there.

Comment: If you set `len32=0` so you only use the scalar fallback code, do you still have a problem?  If so, it's not an AVX2 problem, it's just memory management in general.  Also, try using a memory profiler and/or check for leaks with valgrind on your local desktop, so you know the high-water-mark when running it on this large file.

Comment: coding style: declare `__m256i qCmp;` and `nlmask` etc. inside the loop with an initializer.  We've had C99 for over 20 years, keep local tmp vars scoped to the scope where they're used. Also, you don't really need a `q32` variable; put `_mm256_set1_epi8('"')` as an arg for the function.  Compilers can easily hoist constants out of loops.  Or if you want a var, give it a more descriptive name.

Comment: The 1.2 Go file seems to be fully loaded in memory. I do not see theoretical limits that prevent output to be as big as the input (or even a bit bigger), resulting in a > 2Go allocated memory. Keep in mind that memory allocators are not perfect too and may allocates more memory than strictly required (due to possible fragmentation). The only thing that could call allocations here is probably `push_pair` which is probably called too many times. What `push_pair` does? Can you provide a more complete code (a [complete working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))?

Comment: Additional supporting code is added. The memory might be used up by the output being saved however is is only saving the start and end position of each quote. The large file will contain more than a million quotes each of which requires two integers to save.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Do not show individual functions in separate displays that a reader must separately copy and paste. Provide one display with complete source code, including `#include` statements, the return type of `detect_quotes`, the definitions of types such as `Output`, and so on. A reader should be able to paste the code into a source file, compile, and execute it with no changes. Given the size issues, it may not be feasible to include complete source, but a representative sample should be included.

Comment: For example, a few KB of text might be enough for someone to examine the program and estimate the memory use with 1.2 GB of text. Or you might provide some sample text that, when replicated to fill 1.2 GB, demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Minimal reproducible example is now added together with a decent sized txt file.